# Voltage regulator for AA battery pack

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

**Background**:

I have a [Minseg [M2V3]](https://minseg.com/collections/minseg-kits/products/minsegshield-kit-m2v3-2-dual-drive-segway-and-line-follower) two-wheeled robot.
It uses a battery pack as follows:

6 x AA battery (1.5 [V]) in series (9.0 [V] net).
The current batteries are Duracell Procell AAs. [[datasheet]](https://d2ei442zrkqy2u.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/PC15US12141.pdf)

The device passes the battery pack voltage to an Arduino Mega 2650,
which regulates the voltage to power several IC chips.

The device also passes the battery voltage directly to a DC motor driver:
TI SN754410, a quadruple half-H driver. [[datasheet]](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn754410.pdf)
This receives a pulse-width modulated signal from the Arduino controller,
which states whether to pass or null the source voltage at any given time
to each of two DC motors:
Lego NXT DC motor [[datasheet]](http://www.philohome.com/nxtmotor/nxtmotor.htm)

My controller specifies a desired voltage.
This voltage is normalized (divided by) the **assumed** source voltage,
yielding a number ranging from 0 to 1.
This number is converted into a PWM signal,
which is on for the yielded factor of time and off for all other time
for each sample interval.

**Original Problem**:

The source voltage from the battery packs droop proportionally with motor speed.
At zero speed (zero voltage applied), the battery pack provides 8.5 [V].
At max speed (constant voltage applied), the battery pack provides 7.5 [V].

Recall from above that the calculation for passing voltage to the motor
is dependent on an assumed value.
(I measure the battery pack leads at full speed before use, and use that value.)

I realized I could slightly improve performance,
either by sensing the actual voltage dynamically during operation,
or by holding the source voltage to a constant value.

*For the first method*:
The Arduino analog input is able to read up to 5 [V].
Thus, using a voltage divider (two resistors from + to -)
to multiply by a factor of R2 / (R1 + R2),
[in this case, approximately 10k / (15k + 10k) = 0.4],
over the battery pack terminals (up to 9 [V]),
can serve as a fair voltage sensor.
(Some filtering would likely be necessary?)

*But I wanted to go with the second method*:
I purchased a premade (hobbyist) voltage regulator [[datasheet]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0118ROT2S)
(Yeeco Ultra DC to DC Buck Boost Converter Adjustable Voltage Stabilizer 5.0-25V to 0.5V-25V Automatically Step-Up/Step-Down Car Power Supply Module Voltage Regulator)
I did put the aforementioned voltage divider across its output (for later use); however,
I do not believe this has much of an impact on performance.

**Actual Problem**:

When I turn on the device, there is a 2 second delay without motor use.
It thus turns on as normal.
After the two-second window is passed, when the motors would begin to activate,
the Arduino shuts off (self-protects?).

It is my thought that the series AA batteries cannot handle
the pulse requests from the voltage regulator at its input.
I do not believe that the datasheet provides adequate enough information
to know if I am bypassing a limit.

It does state "2 [A] / 1 [s]";
does that mean a near-linear relationship and maximum of "0.02 [A] / 0.01 [s]"?

If this were the case,
which types of battery material are best suited for such pulses at a AA size?
It would be nice to not go over 9 [V] such that I could demonstrate behavior  with and without the voltage regulator using the same set of batteries; however,
I'm not averse to hearing all of the options.

Comment: This is the closest to poetry formatting I've seen on the site. It seems that if you double-space before a line break you get a "new-line" without a paragraph break!

Comment: Seems like you are taking the long road when what you really want to do is capture the speed/acceleration of the motor and adjust that.

Comment: @Transistor yes.. I discovered that one recently too. This site needs a better set of crib notes.

Comment: Using a voltage regulator upstream of the motors is fundamentally a bad idea.  Go back to the previous method of compensating measured voltage drop; that actually has precedent, and isn't wasteful since it's switch mode.  Though you might want to think about replace the horribly lossy biploar  SN754410 with a FET bridge, too in order to avoid the >3 ohms of effective series resistance in that antiquated driver chip.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Compensating measured voltage drop: do you mean active source voltage sensing? FET bridge: Do you know of any successors in which the I/O line up perfectly and would only require a chip switch in the same PCB architecture?

Comment: @ChrisStratton : It turns out that this voltage regulator has a max current limit of 2A. Probably pretty worthless when I guesstimate the motors to use 1A continuous plus whatever the Arduino takes for itself and the ICs. Still no go for a better regulator?

Comment: A regulator will only make things worse, as it means that you not only have the absurd losses of that antiquated bipolar bridge, but throw away a fair part of your battery pack by setting the regulator output to be the dropout voltage below the lowest sag voltage of a mostly run down pack.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Can you elaborate that a bit more? I get that the SN754410 chip is has higher than desirable impedance. What do you mean by dropout voltage and sag voltage, and how is the pack run down?

Comment: The voltage of your pack decreases as it is run down (discharged).  Further at any given state of charge, it sags yet more under heavy load.  A regulator has a "dropout" voltage which is the minimum difference between input and output where regulation will occur.  10x NIMH AA might be  12v nominal, but would be 11 volts when run down, and might sag another volt under load.  A typical regulator might have a 2 volt dropout.  So maybe you can have an 8v regulator.  Your bipolar bridge then burns another 3 volts internally.  From a "12v" pack, you may actually only deliver 5 volts to the motors.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : I don't follow. I thought the whole point of the regulator was that it would prevent sag despite the load. Or are you stating that the countervoltage caused by the motor (proptional to its speed) - the motor back EMF voltage `V.backEMF = - V.source * k(v.motor)` - is not mitigated by the regulator, thus becoming a source of sag? I thought that the regulator could overcome the sag caused by back EMF.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Also, since you are familiar with the SN54410 chip; do you know if the v.drop is roughly constant or if it changes with load? My notes from someone state to expect a 1.2 [V] loss with a 9 [V] set of batteries.  I wondered if that drop would vary with motor speed or the PWM factor.

Comment: No regulator can prevent sag of the battery pack terminal voltage due to internal losses within the pack.   Bipolar bridge losses are heavily though not entirely load dependent.  If I recall the 3+ volt figure is for a 1-amp load.  The main point is that a voltage regulator is the entirely wrong approach.  If you want to compensate for the pack voltage, measure it and compensate for it mathematically - **don't try to achieve consistency by  making your system always perform even worse than the worst it would ever perform natively** by using a regulator.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : So, ditch the regulator. Use active voltage sensing to monitor source voltage. (I assume that an active voltage sensing signal will need to be digitally filtered.) Would adding a large capacitor mitigate much of the sag, as suggested by Bachler? What would be the best method to treat the losses in the SN754410 - measure the losses at rated speed while upright, and thus use the biggest loss? Measure at different voltages (0, 1/2 rated, rated) and interpolate? Its tough to measure since the device has to be upright, balanced, and moving to get the full physical load.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned in unanswerable form for over a year

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an oscilloscope on the battery, motor, and IC power points?  It may be that your regulator cant quite keep up with a AA battery.  Those things can put out lots of AMPS under intermittent load.  The system may be experiencing a voltage drop when the motor tries to engage.  Electric motors at 0 RPM draw a huge intermittent load, known as the starting load, or starting current.  That is why in motor applications, like your refrigerator, fuses are slow blow, and breakers are delay type.  The simple fix, add a big capacitor to the output of the power supply.  The bigger the better (within reason).